# Working with pandas dataframe and Combining conditions gives ambiguity error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, ambiguous

I am trying to calculate the candle stick pattern called Doji. It requires two calculation of two conditions
values is a pandas dataframe with the historical stock data with columns Date, High, Low, open and Close.

With the if condition I tried to explicitly make condition1 and condition2 bool and also tried it by typecasting it with any(). Both of them did not give the desired result.Printing condition1 and condition 2 separately give appropriate boolean value but combining it with '&' goes horribly wrong.

```
51315    True
51316    True
51317    True
51318    True
51319    True
         ... 
53790    True
53791    True
53792    True
53793    True
53794    True
Length: 2480, dtype: bool
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-3f42eed169f4> in <module>
      4 values = pd.DataFrame(stocks_data.loc[stocks_data['Company']=='TCS'])
      5 values.reset_index()
----> 6 study_candlesticks(values)

<ipython-input-57-fd67b4117699> in study_candlesticks(values)
     21 #     for row in values
     22 
---> 23     if calc_doji(values):
     24         values['Pattern']='Doji'
     25 

<ipython-input-57-fd67b4117699> in calc_doji(values)
     81     condition2=((values['High'] - values['Low'])>values['Close']*min_candle_size)
     82     print(condition2)
---> 83     if ((condition1).bool()&(condition2).any()):
     84         return True
     85     else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in bool(self)
   1581             )
   1582 
-> 1583         self.__nonzero__()
   1584 
   1585     def __abs__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1553             "The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1554             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".format(
-> 1555                 self.__class__.__name__
   1556             )
   1557         )
```

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any suggestions?

Below is the code

```
calc_doji(values)

def calc_doji(values):
    max_candle_size=0.1/100
    min_candle_size=1/100
    condition1 =(abs(values['Open'] - values['Close'])<values['Close']*max_candle_size)
    print(condition1)
    condition2=((values['High'] - values['Low'])>values['Close']*min_candle_size)
    print(condition2)
    if ((condition1).bool()&(condition2).any()): 
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two `pd.Series`, where `dtype('bool')`. You can compare them in the following way. *Without knowing what your data looks like, I've created two `pd.Series` with either `True` or `False`*.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

condition1= pd.Series(np.random.choice([True, False], 100)) 
condition2= pd.Series(np.random.choice([True, False], 100))
```

Then you can compare by doing the following.

```
(condition1) & (condition2) # which returns a `pd.Series` where each row is either `True` or `False`.
```

To find any index position from each `pd.Series` where both values are `True`.

```
((condition1) & (condition2)).any() # Which returns either `True` or `False`
```

From your code, I would guess this line is the issue.

```
if ((condition1).bool()&(condition2).any()):
```

which should be

```
if ((condition1) & (condition2)).any():
```

Comment: I have just tested it with the update you suggested and it has resolved the issue. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Excellent, no problem